# consul container exits with a protocol version error

Tags: docker, consul, service-discovery

I am trying to make a container for consul and it keeps failing with this output, funny, I don't really think it is an error

```
Protocol 2 spoken by default, understands 2 to 3 (agent will automatically use protocol >2 when speaking to compatible agents)
```

following is the command I am using:

```
docker container run --net host --name consul-server -e 'CONSUL_LOCAL_CONFIG={"skip_leave_on_interrupt": true}' -e CONSUL_BIND_INTERFACE='eth0' consul agent -server -client 0.0.0.0 -dns-port 53 -bootstrap-expect 1 -ui -datacenter dc1 -v "/var/lib/consul:/consul/data" -data-dir /var/lib/consul
```

It is a single node fresh installation with latest version from registry, so there is no upgrade or version mismatch with any agent/client happening here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things to fix. First, the `-v` volume argument must be for `docker` command, not for `consul` command. Move it to the right place:

```
docker container run -v "/consul/data:/var/lib/consul" -data-dir /var/lib/consul --net host --name consul-server -e 'CONSUL_LOCAL_CONFIG={"skip_leave_on_interrupt": true}' -e CONSUL_BIND_INTERFACE='eth0' consul agent -server -client 0.0.0.0 -dns-port 53 -bootstrap-expect 1 -ui -datacenter dc1
```

Also invert them (they are /host/dir:/container/dir)

Second, by default Consul can't listen to privileged ports (i.e. 53). See this: https://www.consul.io/docs/guides/forwarding.html, so remove the `-dns-port 53` and implement any approach that they recommends:

```
docker container run -v "/consul/data:/var/lib/consul" -data-dir /var/lib/consul --net host --name consul-server -e 'CONSUL_LOCAL_CONFIG={"skip_leave_on_interrupt": true}' -e CONSUL_BIND_INTERFACE='eth0' consul agent -server -client 0.0.0.0 -bootstrap-expect 1 -ui -datacenter dc1
```

I recommend the [DNSMasq setup](https://www.consul.io/docs/guides/forwarding.html#dnsmasq-setup), it is easy to implement.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply. I actually did look at the document and tried to follow the recurser approach.

   It is worth mentioning that, by default, Consul does not resolve DNS records outside the .consul. zone unless the recursors configuration option has been set.

So I added that in the command I pasted in the original question as -recursors 8.8.8.8 but that also did not help. Any help on that? I need to keep all configuration in containers only.

Answer (score 0):

@Robert Alright, I think we also went a bit off topic here. The real issue is the message it shows and exits immidiately after that.

I tried your example and it gives the same message/error (don't think it is an error though)

```
[root@ip-X-X-X-X user]# docker container run --net host --name consul-server -e 'CONSUL_LOCAL_CONFIG={"skip_leave_on_interrupt": true}' -e CONSUL_BIND_INTERFACE='eth0' consul agent -server -client 0.0.0.0 -dns-port 53 -bootstrap-expect 1 -ui -datacenter dc1 -v "/var/lib/consul:/consul/data" -data-dir /var/lib/consul
==> Found address 'X.X.X.X' for interface 'eth0', setting bind option...
Consul v0.8.5
Protocol 2 spoken by default, understands 2 to 3 (agent will automatically use protocol >2 when speaking to compatible agents)
[root@ip-X-X-X-X user]# docker container ls | grep consul-server
[root@ip-10-201-14-34 user]#
```

Same for recursors example:

```
[root@ip-X.X.X.X user]# docker container run --net host --name consul-server -e 'CONSUL_LOCAL_CONFIG={"skip_leave_on_interrupt": true}' -e CONSUL_BIND_INTERFACE='eth0' consul agent -server -client 0.0.0.0 -dns-port 53 -bootstrap-expect 1 -ui -datacenter dc1 -v "/var/lib/consul:/consul/data" -data-dir /var/lib/consul -recursers 8.8.8.8
==> Found address 'X.X.X.X' for interface 'eth0', setting bind option...
Consul v0.8.5
Protocol 2 spoken by default, understands 2 to 3 (agent will automatically use protocol >2 when speaking to compatible agents)
[root@ip-X-X-X-X user]# docker container ls | grep consul-server
[root@ip-10-201-14-34 user]#
```

Comment: You are still using the `--dns-port=53` which I said that is the problem

Comment: Here it is without --dns-port=53 and still same issue.


` MacBook-Pro-2:.ssh jagatveer$ docker container run --net host --name consul-server -e 'CONSUL_LOCAL_CONFIG={"skip_leave_on_interrupt": true}' -e CONSUL_BIND_INTERFACE='eth0' consul agent -server -client 0.0.0.0 -bootstrap-expect 1 -ui -datacenter dc1 -v "/var/lib/consul:/consul/data" -data-dir /var/lib/consul
Consul v0.7.0
Protocol 2 spoken by default, understands 2 to 3 (agent will automatically use protocol >2 when speaking to compatible agents) `

Comment: Please review my answer. I have also said the -v is in the wrong place...